# Inaccurate Average reported from JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an `average()` method to calculate the average between two values.
The averages are coming off by a "hair" of a decimal value.

```
const measurements = [ 
  { timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.1,
    dewPoint: 16.9 
  },
  { timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:10:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.3,
    dewPoint: 0 
  },
  { timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:20:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.5,
    dewPoint: 17.1 
   },
   { timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:30:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.4,
    dewPoint: 17.3 
   },
   { timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:40:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.2,
    dewPoint: 0 
   },
   { timestamp: '2015-09-01T17:00:00.000Z',
    temperature: 28.1,
    dewPoint: 18.3 
   } 
]
```

For sake of conciseness, I'm not gonna share 60 lines of code here:

Assumptions:

- I have a `query()` method to get ranges from and to a given **timestamp.** In my example **from** `2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z` **to** `2015-09-01T17:00:00.000Z`
- Another method loops through the object and outputs the **min** and **max**
  values with a specified **metric**. My metric is **dewPoint** the **min** and **max** values of the above array is **16.9** and **18.3** respectively.
- Finally (see below) a method to get the average between **min** and **max** values

Therefore this is the result of the explanation above:

```
// POSTMAN result

[
    {
        "metric": "dewPoint",
        "stat": "min",
        "value": 16.9
    },
    {
        "metric": "dewPoint",
        "stat": "max",
        "value": 18.3
    },
    {
        "metric": "dewPoint",
        "stat": "average",
        "value": 17.4
    }
]
```

I want to get the average between the max and min values. i.e. `16.9` & `18.3` which should be **17.6**, however, I'm getting **17.4** instead

Here's the one method that has the actual bug.

```
function averageMetric(measurements, metric) {

  // => metric dewPoint
  // => measurements = the data array in example

  let value = 0
  let measurementsWithMetric = 0
  measurements.forEach(measurement => {
    if (measurement[metric]) {
      value += measurement[metric]
      measurementsWithMetric++
    }
  })
  //=> value = 69.6
  //=> measurementsWithMetric = 4
  const average = value / measurementsWithMetric // Is this the issue?
  // average =  17.4

  return isNaN(average) ? null : Math.round(average * 100) / 100
}
```

Could you help me understand the issue here and also suggest an ES6 equivalent solution of the method above?

Comment: You are saying that you want the average of the min and max issues, but you're not doing that at all. You're taking an average of every value. The result I get for that is `17.533333333333335`.

Comment: could you please show me an example?

Comment: (16.9 + 18.3 + 17.4) / 3

Comment: What is the value of the `metric` parameter?

Comment: the metric parameter = `dewPoint`. Why are we adding 17.4 to the math? 17.4 was the result returned from the `average`

Comment: I don't understand people that downvote questions here for no rhyme or reason. what is missing from the question in terms of explaining the issue and providing the coding effort thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function calculates the *arithmetic mean*, not the *mid-range*. Here is a function to calculate that:

```js
const measurements = [ 
  {temperature: 27.1, dewPoint: 16.9},
  {temperature: 27.3, dewPoint: 0}, // Isn't this the minimum value though?
  {temperature: 27.5, dewPoint: 17.1},
  {temperature: 27.4, dewPoint: 17.3},
  {temperature: 27.2, dewPoint: 0},
  {temperature: 28.1, dewPoint: 18.3}, 
  {temperature: 28.2} 
];
function averageMetric(meas, metr) {
  const valid = meas.filter(e => e[metr]);
  const min = Math.min(...valid.map(e => e[metr]));
  const max = Math.max(...valid.map(e => e[metr]));
  return (min + max) / 2;
}

console.log(averageMetric(measurements, 'dewPoint'));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and for helping me with a solution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not quite how I have it structured my data. The code I provided was a result of a POSTMAN res.body. Please see the edited question to see what measurements equal to.

Comment: @NullisTrue Updated my answer

Comment: sorry for the delay on the edit of my question. I was trying to make sure I laid all the necessary info there. Please let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: So the data contains `dewPoint: 0` if the dew point wasn't measured? What if the dew point is actually *0°*

Comment: ah. do you think that is the actual bug? How would you suggest me refactoring it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189752/discussion-between-null-istrue-and-iii).

Comment: @ ııı I added `0` to dewPoint, perhaps this is wrong on my side. I needed somehow show that the dewPoint wasn't measured i.e. `| dewPoint | (no value)  | temperature | 27.1 |` perhaps it should be `null` instead?

Comment: It would be better to use `null` or just omit the `dewPoint` property altogether in that case yes. But that's not the issue

Comment: No words to thank you enough. You saved my weekend !!

Answer (score 0):

```
measurements.forEach(measurement => {
  if (measurement[metric]) {
    value += measurement[metric]
    measurementsWithMetric++
  }
})
```

is incorrect if you want to get the average of the min and max, (which is the mid range)

Instead, you should try

```
let min = 10**6, max = -10**6; //unless your dew point is stupid this should be fine
measurements.forEach(measurement => {
  if (measurement[metric]) {
    min = Math.min(measurement[metric], min);
    max = Math.max(measurement[metric], max);
    measurementsWithMetric++
  }
})
let average = (max+min)/2;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with `**` operations.

Comment: The `if (measurement[metric])` block will never execute, `metric` is `"dewPoint"` and none of the items have such a property

Comment: ohh sorry! I thought the measurements array contained objects with many properties, and metric was used to select between with property to find median of.

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right, I got confused by the example data in the question. Nevertheless if `measurement[metric]` happens to be `0`, the `if()` block will still not execute